# How to recognize end of line in csv file for sql for LOAD DATA INFILE method? tried Lines Terminated by '' '\r' '\r\n' or '\n'..... nothing has worked

Tags: sql, load-data-infile, mysqlimport

I have tried multiple lines terminated configuration '\r'  '\n'   '\r\n', but nothing works. I even tried LINES TERMINATED BY '', but that doesn't work either as one of the columns i dont need has text with spaces.   also is there a way to skip over certain columns in the CSV data files and input the 5 columns i want using this method without control over the csv files?

```
$sql = "LOAD DATA INFILE '$finalfile' INTO TABLE baa_load_actual_test
     FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',';
     LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
     IGNORE 1 LINES;
     (INTERVALSTARTTIME_GMT, INTERVALENDTIME_GMT, LOAD_TYPE, OPR_DT, OPR_HR, 
             OPR_INTERVAL, MARKET_RUN_ID, TAC_AREA_NAME, LABEL, XML_DATA_ITEM, POS, MW, nexttolastcolumn, lastcolumn) ";
```

```
2022-02-10T07:00:00-00:00,2022-02-10T08:00:00-00:00,0,2022-02-09,24,0,ACTUAL,AZPS,Total Actual Hourly Integrated Load,SYS_FCST_ACT_MW,3.8,2654,ACTUAL,1
2022-02-10T07:00:00-00:00,2022-02-10T08:00:00-00:00,0,2022-02-09,24,0,ACTUAL,BANC,Total Actual Hourly Integrated Load,SYS_FCST_ACT_MW,3.8,1515,ACTUAL,2
2022-02-10T07:00:00-00:00,2022-02-10T08:00:00-00:00,0,2022-02-09,24,0,ACTUAL,BANCMID,Total Actual Hourly Integrated Load,SYS_FCST_ACT_MW,3.8,241,ACTUAL,3
2022-02-10T07:00:00-00:00,2022-02-10T08:00:00-00:00,0,2022-02-09,24,0,ACTUAL,BANCRDNG,Total Actual Hourly Integrated Load,SYS_FCST_ACT_MW,3.8,81,ACTUAL,4
2022-02-10T07:00:00-00:00,2022-02-10T08:00:00-00:00,0,2022-02-09,24,0,ACTUAL,BANCRSVL,Total Actual Hourly Integrated Load,SYS_FCST_ACT_MW,3.8,99,ACTUAL,5
2022-02-10T07:00:00-00:00,2022-02-10T08:00:00-00:00,0,2022-02-09,24,0,ACTUAL,BANCSMUD,Total Actual Hourly Integrated Load,SYS_FCST_ACT_MW,3.8,1005,ACTUAL,6
2022-02-10T07:00:00-00:00,2022-02-10T08:00:00-00:00,0,2022-02-09,24,0,ACTUAL,BANCWASN,Total Actual Hourly Integrated Load,SYS_FCST_ACT_MW,3.8,35,ACTUAL,7
2022-02-10T07:00:00-00:00,2022-02-10T08:00:00-00:00,0,2022-02-09,24,0,ACTUAL,BCHA,Total Actual Hourly Integrated Load,SYS_FCST_ACT_MW,3.8,7158,ACTUAL,8
2022-02-10T07:00:00-00:00,2022-02-10T08:00:00-00:00,0,2022-02-09,24,0,ACTUAL,CA ISO-TAC,Total Actual Hourly Integrated Load,SYS_FCST_ACT_MW,3,22015,ACTUAL,9
2022-02-10T07:00:00-00:00,2022-02-10T08:00:00-00:00,0,2022-02-09,24,0,ACTUAL,IPCO,Total Actual Hourly Integrated Load,SYS_FCST_ACT_MW,3.8,1848,ACTUAL,10
2022-02-10T07:00:00-00:00,2022-02-10T08:00:00-00:00,0,2022-02-09,24,0,ACTUAL,LADWP,Total Actual Hourly Integrated Load,SYS_FCST_ACT_MW,3.8,2363,ACTUAL,11
```

Answer (score 0):

Try 'CHAR(10)' instead of '/r/n'.

CHAR(10) means CARRIAGE RETURN ( enter key ) in SQL.